# Galleria: Won't render without a window intervention?

Tags: galleria

New to Galleria - and trying to evaluate it for an angular system, ripping its image data from a google spreadsheet..

http://codepen.io/kylane/pen/amqWPw

```
function readytogo() {
  window.alert('This is just a prototype');
  Galleria.configure({
    transition: 'fade',
    imageCrop: true,
    fullscreenDoubleTap: true,
    responsive: true,
    trueFullscreen: true,
    autoplay: 10000,
    lightbox: true,
    swipe: 'auto',
    showCounter: false,
    showInfo: true
  });
  Galleria.run('#galleria');
  $('#galleria').fadeIn('slow');
}

window.onload = readytogo;
```

Without the window.alert, the gallery won't render - and I'm not sure why.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, I wasnt waiting for the google sheet JSON to load before rendering...

... my bad.